# Android BLE simultaneous write and notify

Tags: java, android, multithreading, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

Im currently trying to connect my cellphone to a Scale that is constantly sending its data through the UART service of a TI CC254X Bluetooth 4.0 chip, right now I already have most of the app working. The scale sends 18 bit arrays, which I transform into Strings to process, which is properly working, the issue is that I ran into a problem when trying to send commands to it.
Note: The program can send commands and get the proper response if the scale isnt constantly broadcasting data.

Currently as soon as the program detects that it has connected to the scale it runs this:

```
sendCommand(OperationClass.getInstance().getGetTareCommand());
sendContinuousCommand(StatusClass.getInstance().getReadNetCommand());
```

Which translates into this:

```
private void addPacketToQueue(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, byte[] data){
        WritePacket newPacket = new WritePacket(characteristic, data);
        writeBuffer.add(newPacket);
}

protected void sendCommand(ScaleCommand commandAction) {
    byte[] command = ScaleCommandParser.getCommand(commandAction).getBytes();
    addPacketToQueue(writeCharacteristic, command);
}

protected void sendContinuousCommand(ScaleCommand commandAction) {
    byte[] command = ScaleCommandParser.getParameterisedCommand(OperationClass.getInstance().getRepeatCommand(), commandAction.getCommandId()).getBytes();
    addPacketToQueue(writeCharacteristic, command);

}
```

After which I try to actually write the value to the characteristic:

```
private final BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
        super.onConnectionStateChange(gatt, status, newState);
        connectionState = newState;

        switch (newState) {
            case BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED:
                gatt.discoverServices();
                break;

            case BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED:
                connecting = false;
                gatt.disconnect();
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
        super.onServicesDiscovered(gatt, status);
        BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = gatt.getService(UUIDCommsService).getCharacteristic(UUIDCommsChar);
        if (characteristic == null) {
            return;
        }

        writeCharacteristic = characteristic;
        gatt.setCharacteristicNotification(writeCharacteristic, true);

        BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = writeCharacteristic.getDescriptor(UUIDClientConfig);
        descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
        gatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDescriptorWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor, int status) {
        super.onDescriptorWrite(gatt, descriptor, status);
        onSuccessfulConnect();
        sendCommands();
    }


    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
        super.onCharacteristicChanged(gatt,characteristic);
        updateStatus(characteristic);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
        super.onCharacteristicChanged(gatt,characteristic);
        updateStatus(characteristic);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
        super.onCharacteristicChanged(gatt,characteristic);
        gatt.executeReliableWrite();
        updateStatus(characteristic);
    }
};

private void updateStatus(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic){
    if (characteristic.equals(writeCharacteristic)) {
        ScaleResponse scaleResponse = ScaleResponseParser.processScaleResponse(characteristic.getValue());
        if (scaleResponse != null) {
            try {
                updateState(scaleResponse);
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    sendCommands();
}
private void sendCommands(){
    sendingCommands = true;
    if (writeBuffer.size() > 0) {
        if (writeCharacteristic == null || bluetoothGatt == null)
            return;
        WritePacket packet = writeBuffer.getFirst();
        BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristicToUpdate = packet.getTargetChar();
        characteristicToUpdate.setValue(packet.getData());
        bluetoothGatt.beginReliableWrite();
        if (bluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristicToUpdate)) {
            writeBuffer.removeFirst();
        }
    }
    sendingCommands = false;

}
```

The issue is that the *onCharacteristicChanged* callback is preventing any writes to be made, as it is very rapidly updated. I have been googling but I have not found a solution, does anyone have any sugestions? I have been testing my commands with this app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.kai_morich.serial_bluetooth_terminal and there I can always write, even when constantly receiving data from the scale.

Answer (score -1):

I think there might be a problem in the way you are writing.

[onCharacteristicWrite](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCallback.html#onCharacteristicWrite(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt,%20android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic,%20int)) indicates the **result** of a characteristic write operation.

It is called *after* your setValue(). What you want to be doing is:

1. Perform your first write operation (setValue)
2. Wait for onCharacteristicWrite callback to indicate successful write
3. Perform your second write operation (setValue)
4. Wait for onCharacteristicWrite callback

Comment: That is whats happening, the send commands just add the data to a queue, then when "UpdateStatus" gets called it tries to write the first value, "UpdateStatus" gets called at the end of "onCharacteristicChanged", "onCharacteristicWrite" or "onCharacteristicRead"

Comment: Hmm, I don't understand why you have gatt.executeReliableWrite() in your onCharacteristicWrite

Comment: It allows the application to verify that the message will be sent as intended

Comment: onCharacteristicWrite will only be executed once a successful write is being performed already.